# How to use "make" and "form" with "impression"?

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary, collocations

What's the difference between these sentences?

> Make a good first impression on X.
>
> Form a good first impression on X.

How does the meaning change if we use *of* instead of *on*?

Answer (score 4):

The two expressions are used in different contexts and each takes a different preposition. Thus, we say

> to ***make*** an impression ***on*** sb

which means

> to cause someone to notice and admire you:
>
> - He *made* *quite an impression* ***on*** the girls at the tennis club. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-an-impression-on-sb))

So in this case the subject is the object of the impression/admiration.

Then, we say:

> to ***form*** an impression ***of*** something/someone:
> form an opinion/idea: to use available information to develop or reach an opinion or idea
>
> - You should try *to form an impression **of*** the person the adjectives describe.
>   ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/form-an-opinion-impression-idea))

So here, the object of the impression is something or someone else, different from the subject.

Here is another example given by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/form-an-impression):

> It doesn't take long to *form an impression **of*** a place. (*Sunday Times)*

Note that while it is easy to find the expression *make an impression* in the dictionaries, *form an impression* is encountered in less dictionaries and it is also less commonly used.